# "Не удалось преобразовать значение параметра из String в Int32."

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

```cs
string sql = @"UPDATE Сотрудники SET Фамилия = @Фамилия, Имя = @Имя, Отчество = @Отчество, [Код должности] = @КодДолжности, [Код отдела] = @КодОтдела WHERE [Код сотрудника] = @КодСотрудника";

using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

using var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

command.Parameters.Add("КодСотрудника", SqlDbType.Int).Value = код_сотрудникаTextBox.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("Фамилия", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = фамилияTextBox.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("Имя", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = имяTextBox.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("Отчество", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = отчествоTextBox.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("КодДолжности", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox1.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("КодОтдела", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox2.Text; 

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: `...SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(comboBox1.Text);` и далее в таком духе

Comment: : "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

Comment: значит там не число

Comment: Я так понял что он просто в id пытается вставить строку, которая я выбрал в combobox. Если это так, то я не знаю как связать текст с id в combobox

Comment: `= comboBox1.SelectedValue`?

Comment: "Параметризированный запрос "(@КодСотрудника int,@Фамилия varchar(15),@Имя varchar(15),@Отчество" ожидает параметр "@КодОтдела", который не был указан."

Comment: Отлаживайте, смотрите где у вас там в комбобоксе нужное лежит. `MessageBox.Show($"{comboBox1.SelectedValue} {comboBox1.SelectedValue.GetType().Name}");` покажет значение и тип значения. Вообще здесь много зависит от того, как вы эти комбобоксы наполняли и что хотите получить. Эту тайну раскрывать не стали. Еще я не уверен, но быть может надо `@` добавить в параметрах перед именами параметров.

Comment: Я решил проблему банальным привязыванием combobox через "Режим привязки данных". Глупо было с моей стороны не воспользоваться им раньше.....
Ещё в коде я добавил SelectedValue, так что спасибо вам!

Comment: Вы можете сами написать ответ на свой вопрос. И потом примите его.

Comment: @FoleEG опубликуй своё решение в виде ответа, заценим